# var options de geochart google no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

Estoy trabajando en geochart, aunque el mapa se genera correctamente las opciones de colorAxis, title, backgroundColor, datalessRegionColor y defaultColor no se ven reflejadas en el mapa.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['geochart'],
  // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
  // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
  'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Departamento', 'Número de SE', '%'],
    ['Amazonas', 0, 0],
    ['Antioquia', 3775, 22],
    ['Arauca', 15, 0],
    ['Atlántico', 761, 4],
    ['Bogotá', 3792, 22],
    ['Bolívar', 476, 3],
    ['Boyacá', 183, 1],
    ['Caldas', 439, 3],
    ['Caquetá', 48, 0],
    ['Casanare', 39, 0],
    ['Cauca', 206, 1],
    ['Cesar', 218, 1],
    ['Chocó', 7, 0],
    ['Córdoba', 111, 1],
    ['Cundinamarca', 752, 4],
    ['Guainía', 0, 0],
    ['Guaviare', 0, 0],
    ['Huila', 154, 1],
    ['La Guajira', 113, 1],
    ['Magdalena', 175, 1],
    ['Meta', 201, 1],
    ['Norte De Santander', 229, 0],
    ['Nariño', 96, 1],
    ['Putumayo', 5, 0],
    ['Quindío', 147, 1],
    ['Risaralda', 649, 4],
    ['Santander', 740, 4],
    ['Sucre', 24, 0],
    ['Tolima', 247, 1],
    ['Valle Del Cauca', 2586, 15],
    ['Vaupés', 0, 0],
    ['Vichada', 0, 0]
  ]);
  var options = {
    'title': 'Número por departamento',
    backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
    datalessRegionColor: '#f8bbd0',
    defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['#58D123', '#FF0000']
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));

  chart.draw(data, {
    resolution: 'provinces',
    region: 'CO'
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="geochart-colors" style="width: 600px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: mi gente de colombia :D

Comment: He colocado una respuesta parcial, en específico sobre el caso de title. ¿Qué es lo que esperas que ocurra con respecto a las otras opciones? Para lo que estás consultando, no creo que sea necesario incluir tantos elementos en `data`. Véase [mcve].

Comment: Agregué una versión simplifica y corregida del código a mi respuesta. Espero que con esto ya quedó completa.

Comment: @Rubén muchísimas gracias por su colaboración, la respuesta solucionó todos los inconvenientes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cada visualización tiene su propio conjunto de opciones de configuración. En este caso se está usando un GeoChart. Las opciones de configuración para este tipo de visualización se indican en https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#configuration-options

Contrario al caso de un "Pie Chart" un GeoChart no incluye title entre las opciones de configuración.

En cuanto a las opciones de configuración, nótese que al llamar la gráfica

```
chart.draw(data, {
    resolution: 'provinces',
    region: 'CO'
  });
```

No se están incluyendo el objeto `options` que definiste previamente, sino otro objeto.

A continuación una versión simplificada y corregida:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['geochart'],
  // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
  // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
  'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Departamento', 'Número de SE', '%'],
    ['Amazonas', 0, 0],
    ['Antioquia', 3775, 22],
    ['Arauca', 15, 0],
    ['Atlántico', 761, 4],
    ['Bogotá', 3792, 22],
    ['Bolívar', 476, 3],
  ]);
  var options = {
    backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
    datalessRegionColor: '#f8bbd0',
    defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
    colorAxis: {colors: ['#58D123', '#FF0000']},
    resolution: 'provinces',
    region: 'CO'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="geochart-colors" style="width: 600px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: tiempo sin verlo

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales sólo porque no sigues [tag:excel],[tag:google-apps-script] (; gusto en saludarte.

Comment: pues tienes razon, ya termine lo de access, por decirlo asi, ya solo le agrego un par de cosas y listo

Comment: @Rubén muchas gracias por la respuesta y tienes razón en que no era necesario tanto código para explicar la dificultad. Realmente el problema viene en el var options, viendo lo de title efectivamente GeoChart no tiene, pero con la demás  backgroundColor, datalessRegionColor, defaultColor y colorAxis no surge efecto el código insertado, sigue mostrando los colores "por defecto". Espero haber sido mas claro

Comment: Principalmente quisiera que el colorAxis fuera de verde a rojo para el rango de valores y no del tono blanco a verde que lo hace actualmente, a pesar del codigo introducido en el var options

Comment: @jgaitan: Si vas a responder a un comentario, lo apropiado es que lo hagas en la publicación donde está el comentario al que respondes, pero en el caso de que la respuesta sea proveer datos adicionales, entonces lo que procede es editar, en este caso particular, la pregunta.